# Is there a resource for finding the delimiter and seperators for different international currencies?

Tags: language-agnostic, internationalization, currency, delimiter, separator

Specifically I am looking for how Australians would display :

```
$20,000,000.00
```

Would they use commas and decimals in these places? What about other nations? Is there a resource with this information available?

Comment: You mean just a list of countries that use one or the other? This seems to have that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu-Arabic_numeral_system

Comment: That gives me the radix or seperator, but not the delimiter, or the number that would appear every thousandth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, en-AU(Australian) currency is formated $1,000,000 just like American currency, and you can see a nice table: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/InternationalSupport

For more information:

If you have windows then you can go into control panel -> Region and Langauge,  and then change the language under format and click "Additional Setting"  If you are looking for a database you can query programattically with .Net there is the [CultureInfo.NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat.aspx) function which can pull up for different regions.  You can try out the example code.  Also you might want to check out microsoft's website on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688121 .